# Find a solution to a Math.imul() when given a known result

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I know the result of a math.imul statement and would like to find one of the solutions that gives the known result. How would I solve for a value of x that works?

```
Math.imul( x , 2654435761); // the result of this statement is 1447829970
```

Comment: It feels like there should be a bit more details in the task description.

Comment: subject x by dividing?

Comment: You cant just divide out one of the parameters because of the 32-bit nature of math.imul

1447829970/2654435761 = 1.83338915204
Math.imul( 1.83338915204 , 2654435761) results in -1640531535, which means 1.83338915204 is not a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm gonna put the unit test and benchmark of different solutions at the end of this post. It currently includes my two functions, and [@harold's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76267303/10545492).*

##### My original answer

Basically, you want to find `x` in `(x * 2654435761) % 232 == 1447829970`

There's an iterative solution for `(x * y) % 2n == z` with known `y` and `z`. It is based on the fact that any odd number is coprime with any 2<sup>n</sup>, which means there has to be **exactly 1 solution** for any odd `y` and arbitrary `z` and `n`.

Calculation therefore starts with modulo 2<sup>1</sup>: `((x % 21) * (y % 21)) % 21 == z % 21`

Only 2 solutions for `x % 21` exist: 0 and 1. The algorithm picks the one which works. Then goes up by a power of 2, where the second possible solution will be equal to the last one increased by 2<sup>1</sup>. Again, the valid one is picked, and the process proceeds until modulo 2<sup>32</sup> is reached.

However, if `y` is even, then `z` must have at least as many trailing zeros as `y` has. Otherwise, there's no solution.

PS: This works in O(n) time with fixed-width integers. But a variation for arbitrary-width integers (such as BigInt) may explode up to O(n<sup>3</sup>) depending on how multiplication is implemented.

```js
// seriously though, I have no idea how to call this function!
function unmultiply (y, z) {
    y >>>= 0;
    z >>>= 0;
    let bits = 1;
    while (bits <= 32 && (y & (1 << (bits - 1))) == 0) {
        if (z & (1 << (bits - 1))) {
            // there's no solution
            return NaN;
        }
        bits++;
    }
    let shift = 1, x1 = 0, x2 = 1;
    while (bits < 32) {
        let mask = 0xffffffff >>> (32 - bits);
        if ((Math.imul(x1, y & mask) & mask) == (z & mask)) {
            x2 = x1 | (1 << shift);
        }
        else {
            x1 = x2;
            x2 = x2 | (1 << shift);
        }
        bits++;
        shift++;
    }
    return ((Math.imul(x1, y) >>> 0) == z)
        ? x1 >>> 0
        : x2 >>> 0;
}
```

##### Multiplication-free version

On the next day after posting the original version, I realized that the same approach can be implemented multiplication-free. It only requires additions, shifts, and comparisons. However, it comes at the cost of more operations per cycle, so it may run slower because integer multiplications are already quite cheap on the modern hardware. But if the same idea is applied to arbitrary-width integers, it should work in just O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, so it is reasonable to consider.

```js
function unmultiply (y, z) {
    y >>>= 0;
    z >>>= 0;
    if (y == 0) {
        return (z == 0)? 0: NaN;
    }
    // thanks to @harold for the trick with clz
    let ybit = Math.clz32(y & -y) ^ 31;
    if (ybit && (z << (32 - ybit))) {
        // there's no solution
        return NaN;
    }
    let xbit = 0, xmask = 0, x = 0, zacc = 0;
    let ymask = 0xffffffff >>> (31 - ybit);
    while (ybit < 32) {
        if (y & (1 << ybit)) {
            zacc = (zacc + ((x & xmask) << ybit)) >>> 0;
        }
        if ((zacc & ymask) != (z & ymask)) {
            zacc = (zacc + ((y & ymask) << xbit)) >>> 0;
            x |= 1 << xbit;
        }
        xmask |= 1 << xbit;
        ymask |= 2 << ybit;
        xbit++;
        ybit++;
    }
    return x >>> 0;
}
```

##### Unit test and benchmark

Unit test is partially exhaustive, partially randomized. The entire test set is divided into 33 subsets. Each subset is defined by the parameter `tz` ranging from 0 to 32 which tells the amount of trailing zeros in `y` (`z` may have same or more trailing zeros, but not less). I've set the default number of test samples per subset to 20K. For any given subset, if its number of all possible combinations of `y` and `z` is <= 20K, then it will be tested exhaustively. Otherwise, the subset is populated by 20K randomly generated unique pairs of `y` and `z`.

Some unsolvable combinations are tested as well, but those are procedurally generated constants.

I also added `y >>>= 0; z >>>= 0;` to each test function just to comply with how JS natively handles values that are expected to be Uint32.

*Testing on Firefox 113/Win10 shows that the @harold's implementation is the fastest.*

```js
let solutions = {

    blakkwater1: (y, z) => {
        y >>>= 0;
        z >>>= 0;
        let bits = 1;
        while (bits <= 32 && (y & (1 << (bits - 1))) == 0) {
            if (z & (1 << (bits - 1))) {
                return NaN;
            }
            bits++;
        }
        let shift = 1, x1 = 0, x2 = 1;
        while (bits < 32) {
            let mask = 0xffffffff >>> (32 - bits);
            if ((Math.imul(x1, y & mask) & mask) == (z & mask)) {
                x2 = x1 | (1 << shift);
            }
            else {
                x1 = x2;
                x2 = x2 | (1 << shift);
            }
            bits++;
            shift++;
        }
        return ((Math.imul(x1, y) >>> 0) == z)
            ? x1 >>> 0
            : x2 >>> 0;
    },

    blakkwater2: (y, z) => {
        y >>>= 0;
        z >>>= 0;
        if (y == 0) {
            return (z == 0)? 0: NaN;
        }
        let ybit = Math.clz32(y & -y) ^ 31;
        if (ybit && (z << (32 - ybit))) {
            return NaN;
        }
        let xbit = 0, xmask = 0, x = 0, zacc = 0;
        let ymask = 0xffffffff >>> (31 - ybit);
        while (ybit < 32) {
            if (y & (1 << ybit)) {
                zacc = (zacc + ((x & xmask) << ybit)) >>> 0;
            }
            if ((zacc & ymask) != (z & ymask)) {
                zacc = (zacc + ((y & ymask) << xbit)) >>> 0;
                x |= 1 << xbit;
            }
            xmask |= 1 << xbit;
            ymask |= 2 << ybit;
            xbit++;
            ybit++;
        }
        return x >>> 0;
    },

    harold: (() => {
        function inverse (d) {
            var x = Math.imul(d, d) + d - 1;
            x = Math.imul(x, 2 - Math.imul(x, d));
            x = Math.imul(x, 2 - Math.imul(x, d));
            x = Math.imul(x, 2 - Math.imul(x, d));
            return x >>> 0;
        }
        return (y, z) => {
            y >>>= 0;
            z >>>= 0;
            let z_ctz = Math.clz32(z & -z) ^ 31;
            let y_ctz = Math.clz32(y & -y) ^ 31;
            if (y_ctz > z_ctz)
                return NaN;
            return Math.imul(z >>> y_ctz, inverse(y >>> y_ctz)) >>> 0;
        };
    })()
};

class UnitTest {

    #sets;
    #regularSamples;

    constructor (samplesPerSet) {

        samplesPerSet = Math.max(Math.floor(samplesPerSet), 1);
        let sets = [];
        let regularSamples = 0;

        for (let tz = 0; tz <= 32; tz++) {
            let set = UnitTest.createSet(tz, samplesPerSet);
            sets.push(set);
            regularSamples += set.sampleCount;
        }

        this.#sets = sets;
        this.#regularSamples = regularSamples;
    }

    test (func) {

        let sets = this.#sets;
        let regularPassed = 0;
        let regularFailed = 0;
        let regularCrashed = 0;
        let timeStart = performance.now();

        for (let tz = 0; tz <= 32; tz++) {
            let samples = sets[tz].start();
            for (let [y, z] of samples) {
                try {
                    let x = func(y, z);
                    let zcheck = Math.imul(x, y) >>> 0;
                    if (zcheck === z) {
                        regularPassed++;
                    }
                    else {
                        regularFailed++;
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {
                    regularCrashed++;
                }
            }
        }

        let time = performance.now() - timeStart;
        let unsolvablePassed = 0;
        let unsolvableFailed = 0;
        let unsolvableCrashed = 0;

        let samples = UnitTest.unsolvableSet.start();
        for (let [y, z] of samples) {
            try {
                if (Number.isNaN(func(y, z))) {
                    unsolvablePassed++;
                }
                else {
                    unsolvableFailed++;
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                unsolvableCrashed++;
            }
        }

        return { regularPassed, regularFailed, regularCrashed, regularTime: time, unsolvablePassed, unsolvableFailed, unsolvableCrashed };
    }

    get regularSamples () { return this.#regularSamples; }

    static createSet (tz, sampleCount) {

        let maxSize = UnitTest.getMaxSetSize(tz);
        return (
            (maxSize <= sampleCount)
                ? UnitTest.createFullSet(tz):
            (sampleCount > maxSize / 2)
                ? UnitTest.createExclusiveSet(tz, sampleCount)
                : UnitTest.createInclusiveSet(tz, sampleCount));
    }

    static createInclusiveSet (tz, sampleCount) {

        let samples = UnitTest.generateRandomizedSet(tz, sampleCount);
        return {
            sampleCount,
            start: function * () {
                for (let s of samples) {
                    yield [Number(s >> 32n), Number(s & 0xffffffffn)];
                }
            }
        };
    }

    static createExclusiveSet (tz, sampleCount) {

        let sampleCountSkip = UnitTest.getMaxSetSize(tz) - sampleCount;
        let samples = new BigUint64Array(sampleCountSkip + 1), si = 0;
        for (let s of UnitTest.generateRandomizedSet(tz, sampleCountSkip)) {
            samples[si++] = s;
        }
        samples[si] = 2n ** 64n - 1n;
        samples.sort();
        return {
            sampleCount,
            start: function * () {
                let step = (1 << tz) >>> 0;
                let si = 1;
                let yskip = Number(samples[0] >> 32n);
                let zskip = Number(samples[0] & 0xffffffffn);
                for (let y = step; y < 0x100000000; y += step * 2) {
                    for (let z = 0; z < 0x100000000; z += step) {
                        if (y != yskip || z != zskip) {
                            yield [y, z];
                        }
                        else {
                            yskip = Number(samples[si] >> 32n);
                            zskip = Number(samples[si] & 0xffffffffn);
                            si++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    static createFullSet (tz) {

        return {
            sampleCount: UnitTest.getMaxSetSize(tz),
            start: function * () {
                if (tz == 32) {
                    yield [0, 0];
                    return;
                }
                let step = (1 << tz) >>> 0;
                for (let y = step; y < 0x100000000; y += step * 2) {
                    for (let z = 0; z < 0x100000000; z += step) {
                        yield [y, z];
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    static generateRandomizedSet (tz, sampleCount) {

        let samples = new Set();
        let mask = 0xffffffff << tz;
        let ybit1 = 1 << tz;
        for (let si = 0; si < sampleCount; si++) {
            do {
                let y = (Math.random() * 0x100000000 & mask | ybit1) >>> 0;
                let z = (Math.random() * 0x100000000 & mask) >>> 0;
                var s = (BigInt(y) << 32n) | BigInt(z);
            }
            while (samples.has(s));
            samples.add(s);
        }
        return samples;
    }

    static getMaxSetSize (tz) {

        return (tz < 32)? 2 ** ((32 - tz) * 2 - 1): 1;
    }

    static unsolvableSet = {
        sampleCount: (1 + 32) * 32 / 2,
        start: function * () {
            for (let y = 2; y <= 0x100000000; y *= 2) {
                for (let z = 1; z < y; z *= 2) {
                    yield [y >>> 0, z];
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

function toMetricNotation (value, precision) {
    let prefix = '';
    switch (true) {
    case (value < 1e3): break;
    case (value < 1e6): prefix = ' K'; value /= 1e3; break;
    case (value < 1e9): prefix = ' M'; value /= 1e6; break;
    default:            prefix = ' G'; value /= 1e9;
    }
    return value.toPrecision(precision) + prefix;
}

let ut = new UnitTest(20000);
for (let [name, func] of Object.entries(solutions)) {
    let result = ut.test(func);
    let callsPerSecond = ut.regularSamples * 1000 / result.regularTime;
    console.log(`Test function: ${name}`);
    console.log(`- Unsolvable set:` +
        `\n  - Passed: ${result.unsolvablePassed}` +
        `\n  - Failed: ${result.unsolvableFailed}` +
        `\n  - Crashed: ${result.unsolvableCrashed}` +
        `\n  - Total: ${UnitTest.unsolvableSet.sampleCount}`);
    console.log(`- Regular tests:` +
        `\n  - Passed: ${result.regularPassed}` +
        `\n  - Failed: ${result.regularFailed}` +
        `\n  - Crashed: ${result.regularCrashed}` +
        `\n  - Total: ${ut.regularSamples}` +
        `\n  - Time: ${Math.floor(result.regularTime)} ms` +
        `\n  - Performance: ${toMetricNotation(callsPerSecond, 4)} calls per second`);
}
```

Comment: "*I have no idea how to call this function*" - it's called the multiplicative inverse

Comment: @Bergi afaik, multiplicative inverse is `1/x`, while here we deal with modular arithmetic. I'm not competent at the maths actually, so consider this a disclaimer. =)

Comment: I was thinking of [*modular* multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), but you're right, that's not quite it.

Answer (score 1):

While blakkwaters answer is good, there is a simpler and more efficient iterative technique to "extend" a solution that is valid for a couple of bits to a solution that is valid for more bits.

To "unmultiply" by odd numbers, you only need to multiply by the modular multiplicative inverse of that odd number, which you can get like this (using Hensel lifting, which doubles the number of correct bits at every step, instead of adding one more correct bit):

```
function inverse(d) {
    // assumes: d is odd
    var x = Math.imul(d, d) + d - 1;
    x = Math.imul(x, 2 - Math.imul(x, d));
    x = Math.imul(x, 2 - Math.imul(x, d));
    x = Math.imul(x, 2 - Math.imul(x, d));
    return x >>> 0;
}
```

"Unmultiplying" `z` by an *even* number `y` is only possible if `z` is at least as even as `y` (in the sense of having at least as many trailing zeroes), and in that case we can just drop the trailing zeroes of `y` from both `y` and `z`.

`Math.clz32(z & -z) ^ 31` is a trick to count the trailing zeroes. That gives 63 if `z = 0`, but that's OK here. If `z = 0` the result will still be zero which is correct. If `y = 0` then there is only a solution if `z = 0` as well, so having the trailing zero count be 63 is OK.

```
function unmultiply(y, z) {
    let z_ctz = Math.clz32(z & -z) ^ 31;
    let y_ctz = Math.clz32(y & -y) ^ 31;
    if (y_ctz > z_ctz)
        return NaN;
    
    return Math.imul(z >>> y_ctz, inverse(y >>> y_ctz)) >>> 0;
}
```

I didn't put the tests if `y` and `z` are uint32 as a stylistic choice but of course you can put those back.

Comment: Nice tip with clz! Also I included your version into the unit test and benchmark.

Comment: @blakkwater if we're really optimizing for speed, it should be possible to remove the first `clz32` and directly compare `z & -z` to `y & -y` (we still need `y_ctz` for the right shifts)

Comment: Yeah, I left just one `clz32` in my second version. But I feel its impact is rather marginal here.